# unificar .cs con el form c#

Tags: visual-studio, wpf

Tengo una duda, se que no es un problema de programación como tal. Pero no he podido encontrar documentación en internet sobre esto, si alguien más se ha topado con lo siguiente espero me pueda orientar.

Estoy trabajando con `visual studio 2017`, tengo dos soluciones una para `pruebas` otra para `producción`, cuando paso algunos formularios de `pruebas` a `producción` Uso la opción ***Agregar->Elemento Existente-> Selecciono***.

Esta claro que al subir el `.xaml` y el `.cs` como *elementos existentes* suban por separado así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda esta en si es posible que vuelva a quedar unificados así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como es que pasas los formularios de prueba a produccion? podrias explicar un poco mas que estas haciendo, porque no deberias pasar los formularios. Deberias pasar el ejecutable

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder, se crean unas `vistas` en la solución de `pruebas` luego para no gastar tiempo en volver a crear la vista en la solución de `producción` simplemente la agrego ya que solo cambia la `lógica`, si me hago entender?

Comment: La verdad que no. La solucion de prueba te referis a otro proyecto distinto?

Comment: @gbianchi Si amigo

Comment: Cerrando y volviendo a abrir la solucion no se arregla? nunca hice algo asi...

Comment: Nada quedan así separados

Comment: Y si subis solo el form, y lo abris, no abre el codigo vacio? y ahi le copias el codigo de atras?

Comment: Creo que debes editar el archivo `.csproj.` Busca `<Compile Include="FrmContabilidadAG.xaml.cs">`  y agrega `<DependentUpon>FrmContabilidadAG.xaml</DependentUpon>`. Intentalo y me dices si te funcionó.

Comment: @gbianchi Nada ya lo había intentado pero no genera el .cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar ese problema debes editar el archivo `.csproj.` de tu proyecto.

Busca

```
<Compile Include="FrmContabilidadAG.xaml.cs">
```

y agrega

```
<DependentUpon>FrmContabilidadAG.xaml</DependentUpon>
```

Debería quedar algo así:

```
<Compile Include="FrmContabilidadAG.xaml.cs">  
    <DependentUpon>FrmContabilidadAG.xaml</DependentUpon>
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Para evitar que te suceda esto, en principio solo debes agregar el archivo `.xaml` y visual studio importará automáticamente el archivo `.cs` correspondiente.

<sub>Referencia (en inglés) : [[VISUAL STUDIO] TRICK : MAKE A PROJECT ITEM A CHILD ITEM OF ANOTHER](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/05/visual-studio-trick-make-a-project-item-a-child-item-of-another/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción que descubrí es:

**1-** Agregas el `.xaml` a la solución

**2-** Agregar el `.cs`

**3-** Compilas la solución y el `vs` te los unifica.

Ya qué si los subo todos a la misma vez quedan por separado.